# open link out of iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, fancybox

I'll try and keep this short. I have a page with various section. One section has an iframe with a google map in it. On the infowindows i have a link which when clicked i would like it to open in a fancybox over the page(not in the iframe...i can do that). For example if i had a link saying "google", id like it to open http://www.google.co.uk/ over the whole page in a fancybox.

I have 2 different pages and 2 javascripts, 1 for the map(iframe) and another for the main page. The function is in the main page script.

Where i think im going wrong is a) the right call to open the page b) attaching a class to the javascript i.e class="fancybox".

My map info window has this link in it(map.js):

```
<a href="javascript:parent.openSomething();">some content</a>
```

In my main.js:

```
function openSomething() {

//this is where i think im going wrong
//ive tried window. and top. etc

var url = "http://www.google.co.uk/";

document.location.href = url

};
```

My call to the fancy box is in the main page.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your new code is missing a closing quote.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use JavaScript: set the desired link as the `href` attribute, and use the `target` attribute to define where it is opened.

- `target="_top"` will open the new link in the entire page
- `target="_parent"` will open it in the parent frame or page
- `target="_blank"` will open it in a new window.

Comment: You attach a class to a link using the `class` attribute: `a class="myclass"`

Comment: thanks for the response, however i think i simplified the question to much...ill edit the question.

Comment: @Hatzi ugh, a full-page fancybox indeed makes this much more complicated :) Does Fancybox support programmatical triggering of links? If it does, `parent.openSomething` sounds good; it would have to call the Fancybox with the proper parameters. If Fancybox doesn't support API calls, I know some alternatives exist that do

Comment: haha yeah i thought it might...i have no idea to be honest, however im beginning to feel that it does not. Im gonna have to run some more tests. If i could trigger it programatically it would mean i only call the fancybox script once and use it in several places.